# symfony2 empty jsonResponse

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have problem with JsonResponse. Here is my code:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($repoName);
$users = $repo->findAll();

return new JsonResponse($users);
```

So when I use `var_dump($users)` I have arrays with all data, but JsonResponse return me empty arrays.
Does anyone know what could have become ?

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to fetch multiple data records into one response. The syntax needs to be `new JsonResponse(array('name' => $name));`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because of serialization to json. `JsonResponse` uses `json_encode` method underneath. You have array of entities which `php` doesn't know how to serialize.

So what you need is a plain array. To get it you need to use `getArrayResult()`

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($repoName);
$users = $repo->createQueryBuilder('q')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getArrayResult();

return new JsonResponse($users);
```

Comment: Ok thats good method but what when result from my code insert to Twig and it doesn`t work too ? In twig result from my code should work...