# web services with Symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony

I try to write web services in my Symfony2 project that will provide JSON data.

I defined route to choose controller that will handle requests and responses from the web service:

```
_api_v1__get_products:
pattern:  /v1/products/{_locale}.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: ProductsBundle:Api:products, _format: json, _locale: en-US}
requirements:
  _method:  GET
```

The controller:

```
    public function productsAction() {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository('ProductsBundle:Products');

    $products = $repository->getAll();

    //var_dump($products); die;

    return new Response(json_encode(array('products' => $products)));
}
```

I check with a var_dump($products), and everything works.

but in the Response i get an empty json:

```
{"products":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

some help? thanks

Comment: Just a note but you can set the required methods using `methods: [GET]` rather than `requirements._method: GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `$products` is array of entities and php doesn't know how to serialize `entity` to json. You need to change `getAll()` to something like:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('ProductsBundle:Products');

$products = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
```

This will make your `$products` plain array which will be serializable by `json_encode` function.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010384/symfony2-empty-jsonresponse/27010972#27010972) to similar case